# Difference Bwteen two timestamps (DDMMMYY HH:MM:SS:SSSSSSSSS_1)

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to find the difference between two Date_time values? Can anyone please help?

Regards
Asik

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP showed no effort to solve the problem himself.

Comment: I second Dan's recommendation to close this thread.

Comment: Hi Dan Bracuk, I am new to this Community, what is OP, and what is no effort to solve the problem itself?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
with t (first_date, second_date) as (
        select to_date('2016-05-01 12:33:45', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
               to_date('2015-12-15 20:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual)
select first_date, second_date, first_date - second_date as difference from t;

FIRST_DATE          SECOND_DATE         DIFFERENCE
------------------- ------------------- ----------
2016-05-01 12:33:45 2015-12-15 20:00:00 137.690104
```

Note that the difference is in days (including fractions of a day). The dates can be read from a table, or from a function (like SYSDATE) etc.

In your title you talk about timestamp but in the question you say date_time - which is it? You can do something similar with timestamps, but it is a bit different - the difference is in the form of an interval (not as a number of days, or of seconds, etc.)

**Edit**: In follow-up conversation, the OP (Original Poster) clarified he was interested in the difference between timestamps. For the example below, I created a table ts with two timestamp columns and entered values. The query shows the difference. The format of timestamps is dependent on my personal preference settings; the DIFFERENCE is the result, it shows the difference as zero days, 18 hours, 17 minutes, ....   The query is very simple, all that is needed is an arithmetic operation "minus" between the two timestamps.

SQL> select c1, c2, c1-c2 as difference from ts;

```
C1                           C2                           DIFFERENCE
---------------------------- ---------------------------- ----------------------------
02-MAY-16 01.40.07.337000 PM 01-MAY-16 07.23.01.337235 PM +000000000 18:17:05.999765
```

Comment: Hi Mathguy, I have Date and Time field with Millie-Seconds [DD-MMM-16 12.00.02.191000000 AM UTC] - I want to find the difference between two fields like this ...

Comment: @AsikAli - Hi, there is no format like DD-MMM-(something). The month is in digits, only **two** digits, so the format would be DD-MM-...., or it is given in letters, like APR or MAY, and then it's DD-MON-....   Which one is it for you?  Also, in what format do you want the result? As a number, showing minutes, or seconds? I will add an example to my answer above, see if that works for you.

Comment: basically I want to find the difference of [06-MAR-15 11.59.02.191000000 PM UTC] - [06-MAR-15 12.00.02.191000000 AM UTC] and I want to see the results in as 12.00.02.191000000 AM .

Comment: thanks for the help mate...I wanted to minus 60 seconds from my timestamp so I did the 22-MAR-16 12.00.02.201000000 AM UTC- NUMTODSINTERVAL(60, 'SECOND') AS START_TM - but I am not getting the correct results... can you please help me on this ?

Comment: Is that the exact thing you used? You can't enter timestamps like that, you must specify the format mask used. For example, this works:  `select to_timestamp_tz('22-MAR-16 12.00.02.201000000 AM UTC', 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS:FF9 AM TZR') - NUMTODSINTERVAL(60, 'SECOND') AS START_TM from dual;`

Comment: Thank you so much mate, I don't know _tz and TZR and I am not able to find it from google as well.... thank you so much